# Printing a new line every third integer in java

Tags: java, arrays, indexing, printing, integer

lets say i want to print out odd numbers from 1 to 10. but it will make a new line every 3rd number. How would you control the number of items you can print on each line in java console.

Here's my code so far,

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


    int z,t;
    System.out.println("Enter two numbers: ");
    z = input.nextInt();
    t = input.nextInt();

    humbala(z,t);

}

public static void humbala ( int x, int y)
{

    for(int a; x < y; x++)
    {
        if(x % 2 !=0 )
        {
            System.out.print(x+ " ");

            for (int i=0; i<y; i++)
            {
                if(i > 3)
                {
                System.out.println();
                }
                i = 0;

            }



        }

    }

}
```

}

my for loop is a bit weird. i have a counter variable a but never really used it but it's working anyway. the thing is, if I put x , I get an error saying it's a duplicate
I'm thinking, I should make an array. so that every 3rd index, I can print out a new line
but I can't translate it to code

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: How is that not an infinite loop in your inner for-loop? Do you need to update the code you've posted?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Java8 you could do something like this to print the items on the same line Note you could use an ArrayList instead but I am not sure have learnt about them:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter start number: ");
    int start = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter end number: ");
    int end = input.nextInt();
    humbala(start, end);
  }

  public static void humbala(int start, int end) {
    int count = 0;
    String[] numbersLine = new String[3];
    for (int i = start; i <= end; i++) {
      if(count != 0 && count % 3 == 0) {
        System.out.println(String.join(" ", numbersLine));
        Arrays.fill(numbersLine, ""); //for last line
      }
      numbersLine[count % 3] = String.valueOf(i);
      count++;
    }
    System.out.println(String.join(" ", numbersLine)); //print any remaining numbers
  }
}
```

**Example usage:**

```
Enter start number:  1
Enter end number:  10
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
10
```

Try it [here!](https://repl.it/Fs38/0)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need multiple `if` conditions and an unused `variable` in `for` loop, if you just want to print all the numbers and print a new line after every 3 numbers, it can be done with a `counter`, e.g.:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    try(Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);){
        int z, t;
        System.out.println("Enter two numbers: ");
        z = input.nextInt();
        t = input.nextInt();
        humbala(z, t);
    }
}

public static void humbala(int x, int y) {
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = x; i <= y; i++) {
        if(counter++ % 3 == 0){
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```